# Save Data in Adobe Flash Desktop App

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, save

I am making a desktop Flash application (AS3). It provides to users an opportunity to save and open their projects.
I've used FileReference to open project file

```
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
var ourTypes:Array=new Array(new FileFilter("Map Editor type (*.xml)", "*.xml"));
fileRef.browse(ourTypes);
```

and use file content by using fileRef.data.

```
var mainXml:XML;
mainXml=new XML(fileRef.data);
```

User must have an opportunity  to add some data in this file (not only read). How can I save new data in the same file?

Comment: Have a look at this artcle on how to the File/FileStream classes: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/ajax/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html .Note that this is for AIR projects, because you can write arbitrary files to the user's file system with AIR. If can't use AIR, I'm afraid you're stuck with using a Local SharedObject (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#top). With SharedObject you also have limitations with file size. You've got 100K by default and you can ask for more from...

Comment: ...the user but they can choose to deny access to more storage space. Since your code suggests it might be an tile map XML, I imagine the XML will get big pretty quick. So to recap, if you want to save the xml on the client's machine, you can use a SharedObject or AIR, otherwise you might want to consider saving the xml on the server with a server side language(php/asp/jsp/etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a file via `fileRef.save( data:*, defaultFileName:null)`, where `data` is the data object you want to save, in your case `mainXML.toString()`. This will always open another file dialog, unfortunately, and there's no way to work around it, since it seems to be a security restriction.  The only thing you can do is provide a `defaultFileName`, so the user doesn't have to enter one manually.